# Why does vscode have a list of functions in html format but no functions in .js file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code doesn't want to show me the list function. How to fix it?

**When I write code in .html:**

[image]

**When I write code in .js:**

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript might help (look at the section about `jsconfig.json`). I'd guess that vscode doesn't know you're in a DOM context inside your `.js` file, but can obviously infer that in the `.html` file

Comment: Javascript code can also run in node.js environments, where objects such as the `document` do not exist